# How to attach an existing role to serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, serverless-framework

I want to attach an existing role to my serverless.yml file, I have created a role in aws console, my code works fine when I test it in aws console, but when I try to test it with the http endpoint it gives me the following:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

I think is because I did not specify any role in the serverless.yml file for the simple reason that I don't know how to do it.

Here is my `serverless.yml` file :

---

```
Resources: 
  ec2-dev-instance-status: 
    Properties: 
      Path: "arn:aws:iam::119906431229:role/lambda-ec2-describe-status"
      RoleName: lambda-ec2-describe-status
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
functions: 
  instance-status: 
    description: "Status ec2 instances"
    events: 
      - 
        http: 
          method: get
          path: users/create
    handler: handler.instance_status
    role: "arn:aws:iam::119906431229:role/lambda-ec2-describe-status"
provider: 
  name: aws
  region: us-east-1
  runtime: python2.7
  stage: dev
resources: ~
service: ec2
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/), there's a few ways to attach existing roles to a function (or entire stack)

### Role defined as a Serverless resource

```
resources:
  Resources:
    myCustRole0:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      # etc etc
functions:
  func0:
    role: myCustRole0
```

### Role defined outside of the Serverless stack

```
functions:
  func0:
    role: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role//my/default/path/roleInMyAccount
```

Note that the role you use must have additional permissions to log to cloudwatch etc, otherwise you won't get logging.

Comment: hello, i did  attach my existing role using     role: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role//my/default/path/roleInMyAccount     but keep getting the same error {"message": "Internal server error"}

Comment: So go into admin console and check that the role is actually attached to the lambda. If it isn't, then there's a problem with attaching it. If it is, then it's a permissions problem with the role itself.

Comment: thank's bro for you'r help, my code works fine now, i have just adjust the json body.

Comment: I prefer the second option and it works really great for me.